# Eclipse maven install pass argument

Tags: eclipse, maven, arguments, installation

I want to use `mvn clean install -P build-modules-test -Dmaven.test.skip=true` in Eclipse. I have the `m2e` plugin for eclipse. I have found the "Run as --> Maven install" button, but I do not know how to pass the remaining arguments (`-P build-modules-test -Dmaven.test.skip=true`) to eclipse. In `Run configurations` I only see the `Maven build` node, but not the `Maven install` node:

[image]

Comment: Make a run configuration not just plain install. There should be when right clkc project, run as _Maven build ..._ or in image open the Maven build, "New Configuration". That "maven build" is not "mvn build" just a title

Comment: Yes but there I only see "Maven build"

Comment: It's the same. You can define the maven goals there.